# Modifiable Python application architecture

Tags: python, python-3.x, architecture, projects-and-solutions

I develop an application in Python, but I want to make it so that other users can later modify its functionality with their extensions, but I do not know how to organize the architecture of the application. I am asking professionals to advise me exactly how to do this

Extensions need to have access to the application API in order to work with it. There is an idea that perhaps you should start a local host in the application and then let the extensions work by sending requests to it, but that doesn't sound very reliable or guaranteed.

But even in this case, questions remain.

1. Is it possible to protect this interaction between the API server and the extension
2. How to run new Python processes locally with extension scripts, from an application file
3. Can the library be automatically loaded via `eval` to work with the application API, or does it have to be specified via `sys.path` when starting the file? The API file itself should not be in the extension folder
4. How to find and get the child class of the `ExtentionClass` from the module, to work with it later?

```
/app
    ...
    /extentions
        /example
            config.json
            extention.py
    /core
        api_worker.py
        extention_api.py
    app.py 
    app.exe *(pyinstaller build)*
```

Moreover, in the future the application will have to be built through Pyinstaller, and must create a folder in its directory for these extensions

Here are some examples of how I see the file code

```py
# /app/app.py

class App:
    ...
    def run(self):
        
        self.extentions: list
        self.load_extentions()     # <- Get extentions and load to list
        self.start_extentions()    # <- Should load all necessary modules and run them

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

```py
# /app/core/extention_api.py

class ExtentionClass:
    def run(self):
        pass

class SimpleAPIException(Exception):
    pass
```

```py
# /app/core/api_worker.py


class APIWorker:
    pass # Localhost server to commuticate between app and extention


class APILoader:
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def create_extention_wrapper(path: str):
        return ExtentionWrapper.create_from_config(path + "config.json")

    @staticmethod
    def get_extentions_paths(directory: str = "app/extentions"):
        pass

class ExtentionWrapper:
    ...
    def run_extention(self):
        pass # <- Get child of ExtentionClass and call run it

    def patch_extention(self):
        pass # <- Load script using importlib and load API 
             #    to them imported modules (eval maybe?)
```

```py
# /app/extentions/example/extention.py

from ExtentionsApi import ExtentionClass, SimpleAPIException


class ExampleExtention(ExtentionClass):
    def run():
        try:
            make_something()
        except SimpleAPIException as e:
            print(":(")
```

Please recommend literature, articles on the Internet, libraries for such solutions, maybe a GitHub repository with good practices. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question is too broad to be [help/on-topic]. As a design issue, it might be a candidate for [SoftwareEngineering.SE], but check the help center (and search for related questions) there before posting. The recommendations asked for in the last paragraph are definitely off-topic there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Now I have to put a disclaimer on the top that I am not a professional in architecture. I am just sharing some of my personal understanding and experience here. Do not take it all as correct answer as there are no strict architecture suitable for everything.

Now First, I believe there are no one strict way to define your architecture and the most important part is everyone in your group is going with this architecture and familiar with it. The important part of an architecture is to create a smooth pipeline and clear project in my opinion so it is important that you know what you want and you are happy with the structure.

Now back to your project you are doing a very traditional way of managing your project with one main executable program with packages in folder which is a good and simple way of managing smaller scale program with rapid development.

If you want everything to be more clear and seperated, you could try the mainstream Model-View-Controller (MVC). This is the approach I am currently using and it is a good practise when you are developing a medium size, complex and modular program.

A simple explaination of this structure is that you will divide your program in three parts:

1. View - the part of your program that display the content to your users.
2. Controller - the bridge of the business logic and the view, it will receive request from the user or trigger the main processes to create the view
3. Model - The main business logic, which should be the api and extensions for your part, these should all invoked or loaded by the controller.

A simple planning in this structure would be as followed:

```
/app
    ...
    /extentions
        /extention1
            config.json
            extention.py
        /extention2
            config.json
            extention.py
        ...
    /core
        api_worker.py
    controller.py          -call the api worker and extensions, replacing extension api
    app_view.py            -get view from the controller
    app.exe *(pyinstaller build)*
```

This gives a very clear advantage:

1. Seperate each part of development, extensions and core have no relation, each developer can develop their own part and have less impact on other's project, which makes development easier and debug easier(on their own part)
2. You can develop a good habit of TDD - Test Driven Development, Modular Development mean that creating unit test is much easier than having one large program. This thus create a better environment for TDD.
3. The Controller handles the integration of each package and so it is easier to disable or enable packages for debug, implementation and prevent error(disable if error occurs).

However, the cons are quite obvious too:

1. You could easily encounter some integration issue with the controller. People are not into others code and so it would easily create some "bombs" while you merge your code.
2. Speed, it is a little slower than direct access to your logic as you are adding in more layers. However, this is not a significant issue and you are using python so who cares.

I am not providing any documents as I believe if you search software architecture there would be a lot of information in the net and they have a lot of amazing structure for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! 


In general, I imagined that the extensions for the program would work on the MVC model, with separated business logic, GUI and a controller of it all. But thank you for telling me about the pros and cons of this approach


The question was about how to technically load them from the code, by loading the necessary libraries, and it seems overnight I came up with a solution using `importlib`


Thank you again for your answer!